# Using maven, how can include a jar dependency in the package itself?

Tags: maven

In my project, most of my dependencies are pulled down through maven. For the short term, however, I need to depend on a SNAPSHOT jar. Is there a proper place to put this in maven's directory hierarchy, and how do I depend on it in the pom? Eventually the proper version of this jar will be in a maven repository, but in the short term I want to just include it with my project so that anyone developing on it with me has the same jar. So basically I want the exact same effect as if I was depending on this jar from a maven repository, except it will be included in my project.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place it in any directory you like in the project and then use a system dependency.  Create a lib directory to hold the dependency within your project.

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${basedir}/foo/bar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: I would not recommend to put them in src/main/resources. All files in that directory will be copied to the target classpath unless you introduce filtering/exclude/include patterns. The jars would be included in the built jar. Binary files should not reside in a sources directory. Better put them in a libs/ directory. Otherwise your suggestion seems ok. Will upvote if you update your answer ;-)